# When I use osgDB::readNodeFile, how to skip loadding the wrong osgb files?

Tags: c++, qt

I use QDir to traverse osgb files of a folder and save the QFileInfo in a QVector.
Then I use osgDB::readNodeFile to read osgb files in a for-loop.
The problem is that there are some osgb files have inherent mistakes so that the function crushed.
I wish to skip the wrong osgb files and read the next, os I use try{}catch{...} to run the function, but faild.
Is any other way to do?
Thanks!

```
for (int i=0;i<TileVector.size();i++)
{
    try
    {
        saveName = TileVector[i]->tileFileInfo.fileName().left(14);
        osgDB::Options  *a = new osgDB::Options(std::string("noTriStripPolygons"));
        osg::Node* node = osgDB::readNodeFile(TileVector[i]->tileFileInfo.absoluteFilePath().toStdString(), a);
        root->addChild(node);

        if (TileVector[i]->tileLOD == 1)
        {
            lodName = "_lod_01";
        }
        if (TileVector[i]->tileLOD == 2)
        {
            lodName = "_lod_02";
        }
        if (TileVector[i]->tileLOD == 3)
        {
            lodName = "_lod_03";
        }
        if (TileVector[i]->tileLOD == 4)
        {
            lodName = "_lod_04";
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "crushed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code; include the code in your question as formatted text using the markdown facility of the editor.

Comment: I have no idea about the osgb files, but typically files have signature, so the your code logic should be something like if you don't find your file signature then you shouldn't put that into the vector, maybe that is the point you should put your try/catch?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by \`\`crashes''. From what I recall of `OpenSceneGraph` `osgDB::readNodeFile` should simply return a null `Node` if it failed to parse the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it return an Exception in Serializer

```
virtual bool read( InputStream& is, osg::Object& obj )
{
    C& object = OBJECT_CAST<C&>(obj);
    unsigned int size = 0;
    P list;
    if ( is.isBinary() )
    {
        is >> size;
        list.reserve(size);
        for ( unsigned int i=0; i<size; ++i )
        {
            ValueType value;
            is >> value;
            list.push_back( value );
        }
        if ( size>0 ) (object.*_setter)( list );
    }
    else if ( is.matchString(_name) )
    {
        is >> size;
        list.reserve(size);
        if ( size>0 ) is >> is.BEGIN_BRACKET;
        for ( unsigned int i=0; i<size; ++i )
        {
            ValueType value;
            is >> value;
            list.push_back( value );
        }
        if ( size>0 )
        {
            is >> is.END_BRACKET;
            (object.*_setter)( list );
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Exception UnHandled：

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
primitiveSet was nullptr.
```